# Saving GIF into base64 string using Canvas HTML5 javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, base64

I have been trying to convert images to base64 string in Javascript. So far with this code which I found on stackoverflow I was able to convert jpeg and png images to their respective base64 strings. But when i try to convert GIF into a base64 it does conversion but the string always have :

```
data:image/png;base64,............................<string continues>
```

and when i try to open that, gif image doesn't work.

It should be:

```
data:image/gif;base64,............................<string continues>
```

Here's the code:

```
function convertImgToBase64(url,callback,outputFormat){
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        img = new Image;
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
    var dataURL;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat || 'image/png');
    callback.call(this, dataURL);
    canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

I am passing the image from a url for example take : http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/DANCING_BABY.gif

Please help.

Comment: This question is browser dependent. At least IE doesn't allow `image/gif`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453006.aspx

Comment: I am trying to make it work on Chrome using Javascript. I have seen online base64 encoders, they convert the gif to base64 string starting with `image/gif` . But i think they use some kind of server side language like PHP.